# Celery on SQS - Handling Duplicates

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, django-celery, amazon-sqs

I'm setting up Celery using Amazon SQS and I came across the [issue mentioned here.](http://atodorov.org/blog/2013/12/06/duplicate-amazon-sqs-messages-cause-multiple-emails/)

The article mentions:

> under rare circumstances you might receive a previously deleted
>   message again. This can occur in the rare situation in which a
>   DeleteMessage operation doesn't delete all copies of a message because
>   one of the servers in the distributed Amazon SQS system isn't
>   available at the time of the deletion. That message copy can then be
>   delivered again. You should design your application so that no errors
>   or inconsistencies occur if you receive a deleted message again.

I was curious what strategies people are using to handle this?  I wouldn't want to send out duplicate emails.

Comment: Did you see [this follow up post](http://atodorov.org/blog/2013/12/11/idempotent-django-email-sender-with-amazon-sqs-and-memcache/) by the same author? It looks like they used a cache to prevent the same message from being processed twice.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't see that.  I feel like I'm missing something in that code.  It seems like you can only send an email once in that time period, period. Like only one email.  Maybe it's a good start though if I could incorporate the task id?